# Sequelize Typescript - Express

Tags: nodejs, typescript, sequelize.js

como puedo inicializar `Sequelize`?

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:');

class User extends Model {}

User.init({
  // Model attributes are defined here
  firstName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  lastName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
    // allowNull defaults to true
  }
}, {
  // Other model options go here
  sequelize, // We need to pass the connection instance
  modelName: 'User' // We need to choose the model name
});
```

`ModelNotInitializedError: Model not initialized: Member "getTableName" cannot be called. "User" needs to be added to a Sequelize instance.`

**Pero si agrego**

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:', {models:[User]});

class User extends Model {}

User.init({
  // Model attributes are defined here
  firstName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  lastName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
    // allowNull defaults to true
  }
}, {
  // Other model options go here
  sequelize, // We need to pass the connection instance
  modelName: 'User' // We need to choose the model name
});
```

`Error: No Sequelize instance passed`

**Lo intento de esta manera**

porque si es con `define`, no puedo acceder a ningun atributo del objecto

```
    const user= await Users.findByPk(id);
    // user.firstName cannot be declare Model<any,any>
```